# OpenLayer 3 read KML /Document/name

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a way to read the KML /Document/name to set a layer title within an OpenLayers 3 map?

I have some dynamic KML layers, and I would like to read the titles from the KML layers themselves.

I am currently using code like this to load my KML layers.

```
layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: kmlurl,
        format: new ol.format.KML({
           extractStyles: true
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

Currently using OL 3.6.0.
Are there any events I can hook into to get at the raw KML so I can parse it manually?

thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible looking at the code, but PR welcome.

Comment: I have edited the question to add a simplified example of the code I am using to load KML data. Are there any events I can make use of to parse the KML manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with jQuery. Use this following code.

The code take the first element with the tag 'Folder' and give the content of the first tag called 'name'.

```
var url = 'data/my_kml_file.kml';   // your kml file 
var elemTagName = 'Folder';         // the element you want the name

// jQuery
$.get( url , function( kmlDatas ) {

    var myElem = kmlDatas.getElementsByTagName( elemTagName )[0];
    var myElemName = myElem.getElementsByTagName( "name" )[0].innerHTML;

    console.info( "KML " + elemTagName  + " name: " + myElemName );
});
```

'elemTagName' got the value 'Folder' because i don't see a 'name' tag in 'Document' of my KML files. Instead there is a 'Folder' > 'name'.

If you really want to use 'Document' > 'name' , just replace the elemTagName by 'Document'.